# ScrollView shifting upward while tapping on it

Tags: ios, iphone, imageview, scrollview

I am new to iPhone development. I have a image in a UIImageView contained within UIScrollView(zoomscrollView) which is contained within another UIScrollView(scrollViewgalery).

My problem is that while on touching the first scrollview i.e. zoomScrollview, it moves towards upward direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I Hope you need a view similar to photos gallery view. Here u will need a main scrollviewGallery and inside it your scrollviewZoom whose height should be same as scrollViewGallery for horizontal scroll and scrollViewZooms width should be same as scrollViewGallery for vertical scroll. Also Make sure u have enabled pagination for scrollViewGallery.


Your sample code goes here
                [_scrollView setDelegate:self];
    int index=0;
        for (NSString* stringImageName in self.arrayGalleryImages)
        {
    UIScrollView *imgScroll=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(index*CGRectGetWidth(_scrollView.frame),0,CGRectGetWidth(_scrollView.frame),CGRectGetHeight(_scrollView.frame))];
                [imgScroll setDelegate:self];
                [imgScroll setTag:index];
                [imgScroll setScrollEnabled:NO];
                [imgScroll setMinimumZoomScale:1.0];
                [imgScroll setMaximumZoomScale:3.0];
                [imgScroll setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];

                UIButton *btnGallery=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: imgScroll.bounds];
                [btnGallery addTarget:self action:@selector(gotoFullScreenGallery) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                [btnGallery setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:NO];
                [btnGallery setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
                [btnGallery setTag:index];
                [[btnGallery imageView] setContentMode: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [btnGallery setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:stringImageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [imgScroll addSubview:btnGallery];
                [_scrollView addSubview:imgScroll];
            index++;
        }
        [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(index*CGRectGetWidth(_scrollView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(_scrollView.frame))];

Assuming arrayGalleryImages consists of gallery image names.
I used button to add more action on tap.


Try code and manage scrollview delegate methods

    - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
    {
        if([previouslyZoomedScroll zoomScale]!=1.0)
        {
            [previouslyZoomedScroll setZoomScale:1.0];
        }
    }
```

Comment: i have used this code:                                                    - (void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{
   [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollView.contentOffset animated:YES];
},      this helped me to stop vertical moving of UIScrollView. but right now iI'm facing problem in horizontal scrolling, i.e. in paging i have problem.Pagenation is not so smooth.